# js added onchange not executing

Tags: javascript, onchange

In a table row I have the following inputs button, select, date.
The date field is initially disabled, selecting an option other than "selected" enables the date field using

```
onchange="functionName(id);"
```

Clicking the button adds a row. After adding a new row, if I use

```
element.addEventListener('onchange',function() { functionName(id); });
```

The onchange doesn't appear in the code, Developer Tools in Chrome.  If I use

```
element.setAttribute("onchange", function(){functionName(id);});
```

it does appear in the code as

```
onchange="function (){ReqDate(id);}"
```

but doesn't execute.

Comment: Because it is `"change"` not `"onchange"` with addEventListener

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp `element.onchange = function(){};` or `element.addEventListener('change', function(){});`

Comment: "_onchange doesn't appear in the code_" That is correct, it shouldn't, it's a DOM property (when corrected the event name), not a HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the `onchange` attribute represents what happens *on* the `change` event. So in the javascript, you should use addEventListener `change`, not `onchange`.

Credit to epascarello in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the object id as the parameter like so

```
onchange="functionName(id);"
```

worked for the initial row, but not for a subsequent (added) row.

"this" works

```
 onchange = function(){functionName(this.id);};
```

Thanks for the help.